# Spring Data Specifications: use Criteria API to join tables and IN condtition

Tags: spring-data, criteria-api

I have a specification to fetch records of 2 joined tables and using just a single attribute as search criteria as follows:

```java
static Specification<Copy> withDocumentIdentifier(String documentIdentifier) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(
                root.join(Copy_.documents).get(Document_.documentIdentifier),
                documentIdentifier
        );
    }
```

How to implement the same but accept a list of `documentIdentifier`, - I can't figure out in which place to insert the `IN` expression.

I tried it like this:

```java
 static Specification<Copy> withDocumentIdentifiers(List<String> documentIdentifiers) {
       return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
           List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
           SetJoin<Copy, Document> copiesWithDocuments = root.join(Copy_.documents);
           predicates.add(sharesWithDocuments.in(documentIdentifiers));

           return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
       };
    }
```

but t fails as follows:

```
{"timestamp":"08-06-2023 01:06:41","status":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Error occurred","errors":["class org.hibernate.type.internal.NamedBasicTypeImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EntityValuedModelPart (org.hibernate.type.internal.NamedBasicTypeImpl and org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EntityValuedModelPart are in unnamed module of loader 'app')"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me and returned the correct query:

```
    static Specification<Copy> withDocumentIdentifiers(List<String> documentIdentifiers) {
       return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> root.join(Copy_.documents).get(Document_.DOCUMENT_IDENTIFIER).in(documentIdentifiers);
    }
```

which returned:

```sql
select s1_0.id,s1_0.creation_date,s1_0.owner_id,s1_0.owner_name,s1_0.message,s1_0.modification_date,s1_0.public_id,s1_0.valid_until 
from copy s1_0 
join (copy_documents d1_0 join document d1_1 on d1_1.id=d1_0.documents_id) 
on s1_0.id=d1_0.share_id where d1_1.document_identifier in(?)
```